# Unclassifiable statement and Fatal Error: Invalid character '$' at (1)

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am encountering errors when I try to compile an old Fortran code. I don't wish to change the program, but just to be able to run it.

I tried Simply Fortran and I am attempting to build the file, but I get these errors:

```
==============================================================================
Generating Makefile... Okay
==============================================================================
Compiling .\tmod9502.f
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
.\tmod9502.f:97:6:

       INCLUDE TMCOMMON.FOR
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
.\tmod9502.f:98:25:

       CHARACTER*15 INPUTS$,SUBCAT$,PARAMS$,OUTPUT$
                         1
Fatal Error: Invalid character '$' at (1). Use '-fdollar-ok' to allow it as an extension
compilation terminated.
Error(E42): Last command making (build\tmod9502.o) returned a bad status
Error(E02): Make execution terminated
```

Based on this initial bit of code:

```
  INCLUDE TMCOMMON.FOR
  CHARACTER*15 INPUTS$,SUBCAT$,PARAMS$,OUTPUT$
```

Comment: Do you have a fortran compiler?

Comment: Just downloaded one - Simply Fortan - and the code is throwing a build error on the first line 'Include TMCOMMON.FOR' - which, as an include statement, I understand, but not how to solve the error.

Comment: [Quote the filename](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.lang.fortran/gfortran$20include$20unclassifiable/comp.lang.fortran/HWilysusmkY/RY8PvSH4N-cJ)? `INCLUDE 'TMCOMMON.FOR'`

Comment: I don't have that file and can't find that file.

Comment: The source fragment shown is not valid Fortran - use of something other than a character literal after INCLUDE and use of the dollar character in identifiers are extensions to the standard language.  The source may need to be compiled by the specific compiler that was initially used to develop it.  Contact the authors of the source for more information.

Comment: Have you tried the flag `-fdollar-ok` the compiler is suggesting to you? If not, why not? The suggestion is there to help you. And you DO definitely need that include file. Without it your code is incomplete.

Comment: I found the file in the include statement.  As for the dollar signs, I am not sure where/how to use the suggestion `-fdollar-ok`.